# Headers with media

Tags: php, header

In PHP, it's recommended to send the header before echoing an image or any type of data or media.

The problem I'm having is, what happens when you need to send another header to change the `Content-Type` back to text?  A definitive rule is you can't send headers after something has been sent out. Can anyone propose a solution?

Comment: Javascript `location.href`?

Comment: Sorry I meant a PHP solution, but you are right. I could use an href and load texts after it.

Comment: I don't think there is another way in PHP, I suggest javascript way `echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';`

Comment: Or `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';`

Comment: If you want to stick with `header`, use `ob_start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers aren't as dynamic as you seem to think they are. Setting a non-text header `Content-Type` header, writing some media, and then sending a text header after it, will not have the result you're thinking it does. Each header can only exist once *per HTTP request*. Within a single request, you'll have to stick to a `Content-Type` that properly represents the whole request.

Now, if you don't know which header you want to send until further down in the processing, you can always call `ob_start();`, then do all of your processing and output and whichever header changes you like (ensuring to pass `true` as the second parameter to `header()` to overwrite previous values of that same header), and then call `ob_end_flush();` to send all of the output to the browser. However, there shouldn't really be a need to change the `Content-Type` dynamically, as only one will actually be sent to the user.